# type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' in flutter widget test in hacker news

Tags: json, flutter, testing, dart, flutter-test

As you already know there is a boring show of flutter where they made a flutter hacker news app. If I'm implementing the same to learn about the testing of the app. I came across this problem.
**type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'**.
I only implemented three test.
json_test.dart

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import '../lib/jsonparsing.dart';

void main() async {
  test("parses topstories.json", () {
    const jsonString =
        "[24429012,24426500,24426882,24422593,24426407,24427978,24420177,24428206,24426617,24427417,24428755,24422897,24410641,24424910,24422432,24423463,24424462,24428693,24421907,24427617,24426917,24423637,24426641,24425843,24411110,24404595,24428907,24424073,24409543,24422491,24425424,24403827,24422472,24428810,24423544,24423023,24421331,24428943,24422808,24420120,24427311,24427596,24402763,24425870,24426207,24422441,24419441,24423610,24424698,24427706,24428633,24424992,24426131,24426441,24422416,24413394,24421018,24422547,24419042,24423208,24421247,24427930,24428402,24420874,24417015,24408509,24412970,24419081,24407432,24401999,24422092,24406193,24424040,24417319,24416908,24413705,24416807,24402839,24422333,24427247,24419803,24412881,24422720,24415760,24428372,24414497,24402429,24425776,24419660,24426023,24419947,24425121,24428572,24424335,24403076,24428554,24417482,24402202,24401927,24416005,24419844,24425625,24410596,24404189,24414949,24417079,24423614,24423600,24414252,24425268,24418854,24425111,24411344,24407706,24424989,24422729,24423540,24410530,24412179,24410627,24415872,24421934,24407204,24423602,24423534,24419875,24401439,24427083,24406714,24424208,24418838,24426107,24401664,24411357,24424829,24420304,24404814,24419574,24410113,24416112,24427169,24427165,24422599,24422365,24422358,24404002,24412810,24411991,24421073,24427696,24422148,24406611,24401085,24411076,24421034,24421767,24424621,24427045,24425909,24404808,24409093,24412687,24425797,24423484,24407241,24424872,24414877,24413629,24408077,24409334,24404628,24407323,24411540,24425146,24426014,24420692,24403070,24408185,24421020,24408511,24407674,24405632,24426573,24401805,24408324,24406366,24403464,24402419,24411786,24405758,24407005,24426178,24424804,24426132,24426108,24426631,24407849,24407272,24402937,24413746,24403211,24401748,24410681,24405981,24401546,24404742,24411315,24405884,24407232,24421061,24405941,24403351,24423612,24420975,24405776,24425056,24418802,24407601,24411162,24426728,24407321,24410472,24407844,24422487,24402107,24401462,24423332,24401565,24418930,24415294,24415252,24403236,24402467,24423399,24416458,24401246,24403392,24401206,24404555,24414671,24406921,24406829,24408717,24422463,24412936,24404681,24408201,24412549,24418171,24405214,24425068,24411693,24411554,24403566,24419664,24416977,24407122,24409695,24404113,24417890,24425794,24418248,24420592,24408813,24403461,24420359,24415180,24407444,24410575,24403095,24401112,24402543,24409919,24411253,24404671,24416894,24402125,24404357,24406683,24413393,24413737,24406046,24409972,24405876,24413045,24405946,24413554,24405517,24418345,24418856,24408773,24405960,24401221,24410652,24418598,24409327,24418523,24404968,24410991,24411834,24401124,24414153,24413823,24406276,24424567,24423129,24425498,24415528,24422788,24403306,24403255,24414448,24405833,24414301,24401287,24411683,24406577,24403862,24406418,24416379,24421236,24412657,24404704,24420996,24420777,24406341,24405512,24402885,24405253,24404200,24414222,24421155,24408228,24419521,24407430,24411758,24405455,24421761,24405294,24401352,24411207,24403633,24411030,24406818,24402075,24405279,24418561,24401245,24405942,24420567,24405634,24405583,24413574,24404921,24401450,24405651,24410121,24401519,24403647,24406270,24413835,24412451,24405814,24405736,24402536,24405600,24422368,24405438,24425763,24404549,24404182,24410125,24413607,24408109,24406632,24410299,24401107,24405100,24402849,24406446,24404657,24426389,24425252,24409970,24402841,24402617,24401415,24405318,24402404,24403967,24415907,24407797,24412792,24428579,24424763]";
    expect(
      parseTopStories(jsonString).first,
      24429012,
    );
  });
  test("parses Articles.json", () {
    const jsonString =
        """{"by":"dhouston","descendants":71,"id":8863,"kids":[9224,8917,8952,8958,8884,8887,8869,8940,8908,9005,8873,9671,9067,9055,8865,8881,8872,8955,10403,8903,8928,9125,8998,8901,8902,8907,8894,8870,8878,8980,8934,8943,8876],"score":104,"time":1175714200,"title":"My YC app: Dropbox - Throw away your USB drive","type":"story","url":"http://www.getdropbox.com/u/2/screencast.html"}""";
    expect(
      parseArticle(jsonString).by,
      "dhouston",
    );
  });
}
```

json_parsing.dart

```
import './models/article.dart';
import 'dart:convert' as json;

List<int> parseTopStories(String jsonStr) {
  final parsed = json.jsonDecode(jsonStr);
  final listofIds = List<int>.from(parsed);
  return listofIds;
}

Article parseArticle(String jsonStr) {
  final parsed = json.jsonDecode(jsonStr);
  Article article = Article.fromJson(parsed);
  return article;
}
```

article.dart

```
class Article {
  final int id;
  final String title;
  final String url;
  final String type;
  final String by;
  final int time;
  final int score;
  final int descendants;
  final List<int> kids;

  const Article({
    this.id,
    this.title,
    this.url,
    this.type,
    this.by,
    this.time,
    this.score,
    this.descendants,
    this.kids,
  });
  factory Article.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json == null) return null;
    return Article(
      url: json['url'] ?? null,
      by: json['by'],
      id: json['id'],
      time: json['time'],
      title: json['score'],
      descendants: json['descendants'],
      kids: json['kids'],
      score: json['score'],
      type: json['type'],
    );
  }
}
```

widget_test.dart

```
// This is a basic Flutter widget test.
//
// To perform an interaction with a widget in your test, use the WidgetTester
// utility that Flutter provides. For example, you can send tap and scroll
// gestures. You can also use WidgetTester to find child widgets in the widget
// tree, read text, and verify that the values of widget properties are correct.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

import 'package:hacker_app/main.dart';

void main() {
  testWidgets('Hacker News', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    // Build our app and trigger a frame.
    await tester.pumpWidget(MyApp());
    expect(find.byIcon(Icons.launch), findsNothing);

    await tester.tap(find.byType(ExpansionTile).first);

    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    expect(find.byIcon(Icons.launch), findsOneWidget);
  });
}
```

```
00:06 +1 -1: C:\Users\Shary\Desktop\Development\practice\hackerapp\test\json_test.dart: parses item.json [E]
  type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'
  ..\lib\models\article.dart 30:18  new Article.fromJson
  ..\lib\jsonparsing.dart 12:29     parseArticle
  json_test.dart 17:7               main.<fn>
```

Comment: where you are getting an error, the exact line would be helpful

Comment: Please post the full error message since it will contain useful information about where the problem occur.

Comment: 00:06 +1 -1: C:\Users\Shary\Desktop\Development\practice\hackerapp\test\json_test.dart: parses item.json [E]
  type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'
  ..\lib\models\article.dart 30:18  new Article.fromJson
  ..\lib\jsonparsing.dart 12:29     parseArticle
  json_test.dart 17:7               main.<fn>

Comment: article.dart 30:18 ... meaning in your file article.dart, at line #30, character 18... the error is happening

Comment: yes, but i am passing string

Comment: My guess is this... title: json['score'] is where the error is happening right? So title is probably expecting a string, and json['score'] probably returns an int

Comment: I updated my answer based on your error code. Please upvote and accept it if it's helpful. Or let me know if it doesn't solve this problem for you

Comment: The new error is referring to this line `kids: json['kids'],` it is expecting a `List<int>` but it's getting `List<dynamic>`. You can cast the `List<dynamic>` into a `List<int>` like this:  `kids: json['kids'].cast<int>()`

Comment: Glad I could help. Thanks for accepting my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Although my answer answers the question you asked, as pointed out in another answer, you probably didn't want to use `title: json['score']` but `title: json['title']` instead.

You are trying to use an int as a String. Look at the error code, it will tell you which line is causing the error.

Based on your error code, the error is happening on line 30 of article.dart.

This one:

```
title: json['score']
```

`title` is probably expecting a `String` and `json['score']` is likely returning an int.

Just add `.toString()` like so:

```
title: json['score'].toString()  //now it is a String
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong JSON parsing for the score attribute, You have to use the respective field with String which mentioned globally

**Replace**

```
 factory Article.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json == null) return null;
    return Article(
      url: json['url'] ?? null,
      by: json['by'],
      id: json['id'],
      time: json['time'],
      title: json['score'], // This should be title as score you alredy added at the bottom
      descendants: json['descendants'],
      kids: json['kids'],
      score: json['score'],
      type: json['type'],
    );
  }
```

**With**

```
 factory Article.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json == null) return null;
    return Article(
      url: json['url'] ?? null,
      by: json['by'],
      id: json['id'],
      time: json['time'],
      title: json['title'],
      descendants: json['descendants'],
      kids: json['kids'],
      score: json['score'],
      type: json['type'],
    );
  }
```

Comment: @Shahryar Rafique: Completly disagree with you my answer is correct if I am not wrong as you are using the wrong attribute.  Could you justify why it's not accurate?